# How to replace all the formulas with the values they have calculated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Lets say I have a sheet called Sheet1, and a sheet called Sheet2

On sheet 2 I have formulas which copy values from sheet one, in the fashion of:

```
='Sheet1'!A1
='Sheet1'!A2
='Sheet1'!A3
```

There is no consistent row or column count, it might be 5X10, or it might be 20X50 rows/columns.

I then want to make a script which will take the value that has been calculated in each cell, and replace the formula with that value.

The objective is to preserve the values without creating a reference error when I later delete Sheet1. Is there a simple way to do this using a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getDisplayValues()` and `setValues()`

```
function destroyFormulas() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange("A1:B3"), //or getDataRange()
    values = rng.getDisplayValues(); //or getValues()
  rng.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Perfect for my purpose, and very simple, thank you very much good sir.